# How to estimate the mean and standard deviation from a median and 95% confidence interval

Tags: standard-deviation, confidence-interval, median

Almost all clinical trial PFS results only provide a median PFS value with its corresponding median 95% confidence interval (based on NIH data). Because I want to compare multiple clinical trial results I have to do conduct a meta-analysis on this data. To do this however, requires that I know the mean and standard deviation. I am fully aware of hozo et al who describes a way to estimate the mean and standard deviation from a median and a range....but I do not have a range only the 95% confidence interval. I am very surprised that so far, nothing in google has addressed this issue, considering that clinical trials primarily provide the median and the interval. Any help would be greatly appreciated, and I am sure others will need this questioned answered as well.